# How to use Momondo web service to find flights?

Tags: web-services, soap, asmx

Someone's experienced with Momodo API(ASMX) for flights search?
I try a simple http GET query: `https://www.momondo.com//Momondo.asmx/StartFlightSearch?orig=tlv&dest=nyc&departDate=2018-09-09&returnDate=2018-09-12&oneway=false&live=true` but I always get an empty XML.

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced what you describe where the response is either empty or only containing null or 0. My guess is that the soap API might not be active. However, I did have some success using an [unofficial API for Android](https://github.com/5ms/Momondo-API) (i think) to collect flight info.

Basically, what you have to do to get info flight search info is consisting of two steps:

1. Post to `FlightSearch`
2. Grab the `SearchId` and `EngineId`
3. Do a GET request to `FlightSearch/<SearchId>/<EngineId>` until you get a response (it might take a couple of tries)

A couple of things to note where is that you might get `null` as a response at any time in step 3 and also that the response don't seems to be persistent. So you need to store the response as soon as you get anything back, because it will disappear after a while and become `null` again.

The github project readme also have good examples of payload structure so I will exclude it here.